# JSOM - Load items with fields

Tags: 2010, javascript, jsom

I've got an issue when loading data with the `jsom` (`JavaScript`).
I've included all fields, I want to load:

```
this.context.load(this.items, 'Include(ID,DocIcon,LinkFilename,FileRef,FileLeafRef,Title,ContentType,SupplierPGProduct,DocumentLanguage,Country,Customer,Industry,SubCategory,BusinessUnit,ValidityVersion,InternalUse,RestrictedToSpecificCustomer,ReportNo,Modified,ApprovedBy,UploadedBy,Invalid,File_x0020_Size,_dlc_DocId,KeyDocument)');
```

The issue is, that the request is working, when I delete the last field `KeyDocument`. This field is not present in all content types, but I have several fields, which are not present in all content types (i.e. `SubCategory`, `Report` etc.). When I add `KeyDocument` I always get the error:

> An error occurred while fetching data. Please contact the system
>   adminstrator.

Except, when I just query the content types, which have the field `KeyDocument`. This seems to me very weird, doesn't it? Can anybody help?

Comment: what is the type of the KeyDocument field?

Comment: Boolean (Yes/No)